# Reference a java nested class in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to read some data from hadoop into an RDD in Spark using the interactive Scala shell but I'm having trouble accessing some of the classes I need to deserialise the data.

I start by importing the necessary class

```
import com.example.ClassA
```

Which works fine. `ClassA` is located in a jar in the 'jars' path and has `ClassB` as a public static nested class

I'm then trying to use `ClassB` like so:

```
val rawData = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(dataPath, classOf[com.exmple.mapreduce.input.Format[com.example.ClassA$ClassB]], classOf[org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable], classOf[com.example.ClassA$ClassB])
```

This is slightly complicated by one of the other classes taking `ClassB` as a type, but I think that should be fine.

When I execute this line, I get the following error:

```
<console>:17: error: type ClassA$ClassB is not a member of package com.example
```

I have also tried using the import statement

```
import com.example.ClassA$ClassB
```

and it also seems fine with that.

Any advice as to how I could proceed to debug this would be appreciated

Thanks for reading.

update:

Changing the '$' to a '.' to reference the nested class seems to get past this problem, although I then got the following syntax error:

```
'<console>:17: error: inferred type arguments [org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable,com.example.ClassA.ClassB,com.example.mapredu‌​ce.input.Format[com.example.ClassA.ClassB]] do not conform to method newAPIHadoopFile's type parameter bounds [K,V,F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]]
```

Comment: I think you mean [nested](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) class, not [subclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: I should mention, I'm using Spark 1.2.0

Comment: Sorry, yes it's a nested class not a subclass - my bad

Comment: have you tried using `com.example.ClassA.ClassB`?

Comment: Just had a go with that and got '<console>:17: error: inferred type arguments [org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable,com.example.ClassA.ClassB,com.example.mapreduce.input.Format[com.example.ClassA.ClassB]] do not conform to method newAPIHadoopFile's type parameter bounds [K,V,F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]]'.  Would that imply it's gotten past any class issues it had?

Comment: Yes, now your issue has to do with wrong usage of `sc.newAPIHadoopFile`. Now that your problem has changed, please update the question with a well formatted error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the types that the `newAPIHadoopFile` expects:

```
K,V,F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[K,V]
```

the important part here is that the generic type `InputFormat` expects the types `K` and `V`, i.e. the exact types of the first two parameters to the method.

In your case, the third parameter should be of type

```
F <: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat[LongWritable, ClassA.ClassB]
```

does your class extend `FileInputFormat<LongWritable, V>`?

Comment: Yes, it extends 'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat' which in turn extends 'org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat'

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer here; my 'Format' class is declared as 'Format<V extends Message> extends FileInputFormat<NullWritable, V>' so it only takes one type parameter directly.

Comment: @user1111284 please post the signature of your Format class and the hierarchy of its type parameters

Comment: Does `LongWritable` extend `NullWritable` and does `ClassA.ClassB` extend `Message`?

Comment: Right, of course - NullWritable does not extend LongWritable; swapping that out in the command has fixed it. Thanks for your help